# How to display images in grid in android?

Tags: android-layout, android-imageview, android, android-image

I want to display 3 images in a grid as below.

[image]

Here the images to be displayed will be selected by the user from gallery. What kind of layout should I prefer for that? Please help.

Comment: To be frank, I fear you must override the components and implement your own logic to be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Check this post, it will teach you how to [Implement a GridView with Auto Resized Images on Android.](http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/11/01/gridview-with-auto-resized-images-on-android)

Basically you will have to work with an Adapter where you populate with an array of images.

**Of course you can modify the code of the post to fit your purpose.**

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to draw your own shape for the images, you should create your own **View** subclass. Creating your own **View** subclasses gives you precise control over the appearance and function of a screen element.

Check this link about [Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).

---

Hope this helps you. =)

Comment: thanks for answering but in your suggested post images are displayed in square or rectangle. But i have to display in uneven shape. That is my actual problem.